I'm planning to copyright my first short novel. What if after I copyright it, it needs revision?
I have finished my first short novel of one hundred pages with approximately 55,000 words. I'd like to register it with the copyright office. I know I don't have to, that it's already copyrighted if it's fixed in a tangible form, which it is (hard copy, flash drive, and two external hard drives).
But I'd like to register it anyway. If I do, and I get a copyright number, what happens if I discover there are some grammatical or minor changes I need to make? Do I submit the revised copy and does it overwrite the original? Or do I need to copyright the revised copy? If the second scenario (copyright the revised), will I then have two copyrights?
I reside in the U.S.

If you only make minor changes (e.g. correcting spelling) it is still considered the same work and will be covered by the same registration. If you make fundamental changes (e.g. adding a chapter) it is considered a derivative work and needs its own copyright registration. (See Registering a Work on copyright.gov.)

Thank you for your swift reply. A few follow-up questions to your answer.
I understand that adding one or more chapters is a fundamental change.
What if I change one page, or one paragraph, or a few scattered sentences here and there. Would that be considered fundamental or minor changes?
Also, what if I do make a fundamental change and I need to register my novel again, do I then have two copyrights? Do they mark them as "original" and "derivative"? Or do I just go by the copyright number as to which is which?
Apologies if these are simplistic questions that most people know.

@R.P. There is no clear definition of how much change turns a revision from a version of the original work into a new, derivative work. If you register a derivative work, you will then have two works registered, the original with one number and the derivative work with another. When you register a derivative work, you indicate the original on which it is based.

Thank you for your swift replies. I'll go to that copyright link that you posted and get more information there. As a side note, there must be clear definitions of what constitutes fundamental vs minor changes. The copyright office can't just let that go as unclear. If I changed a paragraph. Fundamental or minor? If I changed a page. Fundamental or minor? Changed 20 sentences throughout the 55,000 words. Fundamental or minor? Changed 100 sentences throughout the 55,000 words.Fundamental or minor? There must be clarification otherwise what an author thinks is true, the copyright office may not.

@R.P. There is no clear legal definition of how much change is necessary for a revision to constitute a derivative work. As Wikipedia says: "The statutory definition [that is, the definition in the text of the laws] is incomplete and the concept of derivative work must be understood with reference to explanatory case law." That is, courts of law decide on a case by case basis what constitutes a derviative work and what doesn't. These rulings can then help us understand what might be considered a derivative work by a court of law. But we don't know for sure before a court of law has decided.

That said, anyone who copies the revised version is also copying a big chunk of the original registered version. So you haven't lost protection.

According to LegalZoom, when you hold the Copyright to an original work, you by definition also hold the Copyright to any derivative work, which includes "A new, updated, or revised, edition of a book".
It also includes derivative works such as a screenplay, or even sequels. Now that last is important, since if that holds up, you could save considerable expense on new copyrights to additional entries in a series!

But the changes (e.g. a new chapter) aren't covered by the copyright of the original!

A new chapter would be a revised edition of a book. So according to both LegalZoom and the US Copyright office, it's covered.

To add to that comment, the Copyright office does seem to have ambiguous information. I think the key might be on your page it says "may" qualify for a new copyright. On the information I found, it indicated that even an entire sequel may be covered under the original copyright. LOL Unless I had a best seller on my hands, I sure as hell wouldn't pay another $85 to protect one chapter. If self-published, which is common, the average book does't even gross $100.

Excuse me, less for one work by one author. I typically register a batch at once.
